# is there a way to easier add a variable to several files?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a generator class that generates data for an image.

to add a variable to the generator code i need:

1. add it to the settings dataclass
2. then to .toml
3. then in the toml parser for dataclass
4. and then call it in the generator code

question
is there a way to make it easier to add a variable?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The reason this was **downvoted** is because there is not enough info or context to be able to answer the question. Therefore, please provide more info preferably as code, and also consider add [tag:python] if question is not 3.x specific (since python 3 is the de-facto standard now anyway).